NX Monorepo Angular site not opening in iOS
I have angular application built using NX monorepo. I can access the site on -

windows - all browsers
Mobile (Android) - all
mac - only chrome, not safari
iPad - None
mobile (iOS) - none

I tried putting logs on application module and it prints -
<app-root> not found for all mac and ios browsers.
Below is .browserlist content -
 last 2 Chrome versions
 last 1 Firefox version
 last 2 Edge major versions
 last 2 Safari major versions
 last 2 iOS major versions
 Firefox ESR

ng version -
Angular CLI: 16.1.4
Node: 19.8.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 9.6.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 16.1.4
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, pwa, router, service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1601.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.4
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.4
@schematics/angular             16.1.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.1.6


Do you have code somewhere to test? I built a lot of application with angular in combination with nx and never experience this. But the index.html is same & correct?

I can post index.html. Whole code is internal to organization and I wont be able to share here.

We were able to resolve this after reviewing the code. There was one circular dependency between 2 libraries. It was not complaining in build as well as in other browsers except iOS.
